Elliptic curve addtion not working in some specific cases
I posted similar question on the StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78828295/cuda-elliptic-curve-addtion-not-working-in-some-specific-cases) but it might be better suited here.
I am implementing elliptic curve addition in CUDA. My current implementation works for most of point pairs but there are some specific pairs that get wrong results. I assume there might be some issue with math in my algorithm but I can't see it.
Here is function that is doing the addition operation:
__device__ dev_EC_point add_points(env192_t bn_env, const dev_EC_point &P1, const dev_EC_point &P2, const dev_Parameters &params)
{
    if (cgbn_equals(bn_env, P1.x, P2.x) && cgbn_equals(bn_env, P1.y, P2.y))
    {
        return double_point(bn_env, P1, params);
    }

    env192_t::cgbn_t t2;
    if (cgbn_sub(bn_env, t2, P1.x, P2.x)) // x1 - x2 mod Pmod
    {
        printf("BREAKPOINT 1\n");
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t2, P2.x, P1.x);
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t2, params.Pmod, t2);
    }


    cgbn_modular_inverse(bn_env, t2, t2, params.Pmod); // 1/(x1-x2) mod Pmod

    // Montgomery space

    env192_t::cgbn_t x1, y1, x2, y2;

    uint32_t np0;
    np0 = cgbn_bn2mont(bn_env, x1, P1.x, params.Pmod);
    cgbn_bn2mont(bn_env, y1, P1.y, params.Pmod);
    cgbn_bn2mont(bn_env, x2, P2.x, params.Pmod);
    cgbn_bn2mont(bn_env, y2, P2.y, params.Pmod);
    cgbn_bn2mont(bn_env, t2, t2, params.Pmod);

    env192_t::cgbn_t t1;

    if (cgbn_sub(bn_env, t1, y1, y2)) // y0 - y1 mod Pmod
    {
        printf("BREAKPOINT 2\n");
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t1, y2, y1);
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t1, params.Pmod, t1);
    }

    env192_t::cgbn_t s, s_sq, x3, y3, t3;

    cgbn_mont_mul(bn_env, s, t1, t2, params.Pmod, np0); // s = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) mod Pmod // tested

    cgbn_mont_sqr(bn_env, s_sq, s, params.Pmod, np0); // s^2 mod Pmod // tested

    cgbn_add(bn_env, t3, x1, x2); // x1 + x2

    if (cgbn_sub(bn_env, x3, s_sq, t3)) // x3 = s^2 - x1 - x2 // mod Pmod
    {
        printf("BREAKPOINT 4\n");
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, x3, t3, s_sq);
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, x3, params.Pmod, x3);
    }

    if (cgbn_sub(bn_env, t3, x1, x3)) // t3 = x1 - x3 // mod Pmod
    {
        printf("BREAKPOINT 5\n");
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t3, x3, x1);
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, t3, params.Pmod, t3);
    }

    cgbn_mont_mul(bn_env, t3, t3, s, params.Pmod, np0);

    if (cgbn_sub(bn_env, y3, t3, y1))
    {
        printf("BREAKPOINT 6\n");
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, y3, y1, t3);
        cgbn_sub(bn_env, y3, params.Pmod, y3);
    }

    cgbn_mont2bn(bn_env, x3, x3, params.Pmod, np0);
    cgbn_mont2bn(bn_env, y3, y3, params.Pmod, np0);

    // cgbn_sub(bn_env, x3, s_sq, t1);

    return dev_EC_point{x3, y3};
}

CGBN library API for reference: https://github.com/NVlabs/CGBN/blob/master/docs/CGBN.md
The use-case is for very specific curve parameters:
p = 0x62CE5177412ACA899CF5
r = 0x1CE4AF36EED8DE22B99D

a = 0x39C95E6DDDB1BC45733C
b = 0x1F16D880E89D5A1C0ED1

n = 0x62CE5177407B7258DC31

P_x = 0x315D4B201C208475057D
P_y = 0x035F3DF5AB370252450A

Q_x = 0x0679834CEFB7215DC365
Q_y = 0x4084BC50388C4E6FDFAB

F = GF(p)
E = EllipticCurve(F, [a, b])

P = E(P_x, P_y)
Q = E(Q_x, Q_y)

The pairs for which I get wrong results with my implementation:
A = Q * 1001
B = Q * 20
R = A + B # got wrong answer during tests

A = P * 15
B = Q
R = A + B # got wrong answer during tests 

Some working pairs:
A = P * 10
B = Q
R = A + B

A = P * 10
B = Q * 10
R = A + B

A = P * 20
B = Q * 10
R = A + B
```


Your order curve is 466597814831947642887217 which is prime, however, we see Montgomery around, if this is the Montgomery ladder, it requires the curve order to have a factor 4.

I don’t know about Montgomery ladder, is it the same as Montgomery reduction? And if this is the problem, wouldn’t it make all calculations wrong?

No, it's not related, however, it is the same person (RIP). First, you should stick to standard point addition and doubling. Then maybe you want to use Joce'ladder which is for prime curves.

Ok, you are using a library uses Mongomery Reduction to fasten the calculation. Can you write down your addition and doubling algorithms? Typically you have algorithm implementation issue, that is off-topic here..

But the function I wrote in post is only about algorithm I use. It using a CGBN library for math primitives like adding, substracting or muliplication on large numbers. I can write down exact math operations in more formal way if it’s necessary.

We are not interested in your big number library, which you must test before going to point addition and doubling formulas, and I'm almost sure that they are not there since I don't see the slope

If you mean the slope = lambda (according to post you linked) its calculated and stored under s symbol. Moreover for most points I tested my function, it calculates correct results. So I think there might be some edge cases for computation where the steps I do are wrong

Unrelated to your question: I see that you're doing a modular inverse for every addition operation.  If you need the $(x,y)$ point format after every addition (e.g. because you're doing GiantStep/BabyStep), that's appropriate.  If you're doing point multiplication, or searching for a specific point value, using projective coordinates would be faster (albeit more complex)

I am doing Rho Pollard type of collision search, so I think is the same case as with Giant/BabyStep, right?

One guess: at the line:
 cgbn_add(bn_env, t3, x1, x2); // x1 + x2

the resulting t3 may be greater than $p$, which may lead to other intermediate values being out of the range $[0,p)$.  This might cause the latter cgbn_mont_mul to misbehave.
I haven't worked with this bignum library - however I find it plausible that their Montgomery Multiplication implementation makes that assumption (and it should be easy to test...)

Thanks, you're right, that was the problem. Additional condition and then reduction mod p fixed it.
